# Find the relationships and number of relations with given name

Tags: c#, .net, graph-theory

[image]In the diagram ‘N’, we have a set of users ‘U’ who are having relationship ‘R’
between each other.

So, N = { U, R } where U = { Ramesh, Suresh, .. etc } & R = { Mahesh_Seema, Mahesh_Suresh, Puru_Seema, etc..}
For example, Mahesh is related to Seema, Puru and Seema where as Umesh is related to Keshav.

I want to find out the number of relationships ‘R’’ for any given user ‘U’.

How to create the dataset using the diagram.

Examples:
 **Input** = Mahesh
**Output** = 3 { Suresh, Puru, Seema}

What should be the best algorithm and Data Structure for this problem??

Comment: What you have is a Graph.  The Graph has loops so you would need to use Dijksta's Algorithm.  So normally you would have nodes with list of neghbors.

Comment: @jdweng: which data-structure is best for storing this kind of relation based data?

Comment: The structure would be Node (Class) with a Name and a List of Neighbor Nodes.

Answer (score 1):

If your data are static, you could use a [`Lookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2).

> A `Lookup<TKey,TElement>` resembles a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`. The difference is that a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` maps keys to single values, whereas a `Lookup<TKey,TElement>` maps keys to collections of values.

Usage example:

```
var relationships = new List<(string, string)>()
{
    ("Mahesh", "Puru"),
    ("Mahesh", "Seema"),
    ("Mahesh", "Suresh"),
    ("Puru", "Seema"),
    ("Seema", "Suresh"),
    ("Seema", "Kishor"),
    ("Seema", "Umesh"),
    ("Seema", "Ramesh"),
    ("Kishor", "Keshav"),
    ("Umesh", "Keshav"),
    ("Ramesh", "Keshav"),
};
var all = relationships.Concat(relationships.Select(r => (r.Item2, r.Item1)));
var lookup = all.ToLookup(r => r.Item1, r => r.Item2);
Console.WriteLine($"Mahesh => {String.Join(", ", lookup["Mahesh"])}");
Console.WriteLine($"Seema  => {String.Join(", ", lookup["Seema"])}");
Console.WriteLine($"Umesh  => {String.Join(", ", lookup["Umesh"])}");
Console.WriteLine($"Keshav => {String.Join(", ", lookup["Keshav"])}");
```

Output:

```xml
Mahesh => Puru, Seema, Suresh
Seema  => Suresh, Kishor, Umesh, Ramesh, Mahesh, Puru
Umesh  => Keshav, Seema
Keshav => Kishor, Umesh, Ramesh
```

If your data are not static, meaning that you need to dynamically insert and remove relationships from the data structure, then you can't use a `Lookup`. In this case I think you could use something based on a `Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>`.